# Telegram Bot (new Update in new Thread) with telegrambots-spring-boot-starter

Tags: java, concurrency, telegram-bot

I wrote a LongPolling bot, that works with one Update at a time. 
I want it to work with 2 or more of Updates by multi threading.
Here example what i mean. I found this example in Performance Optimizations (Python Telegram Bot) article.

> Example: You're running the Echobot and two users (User A and User B)
>   send a message to the bot at the same time. Maybe User A was a bit
>   quicker, so his request arrives first, in the form of an Update object
>   (Update A). The Dispatcher checks the Update and decides it should be
>   handled by the handler with the callback function named echo. At the
>   same time, the Update of User B arrives (Update B). But the Dispatcher
>   is not finished with Update A. It calls the echo function with Update
>   A, which sends a reply to User A. Sending a reply takes some time (see
>   Server location), and Update B remains untouched during that time.
>   Only after the echo function finishes for Update A, the Dispatcher
>   repeats the same process for Update B.

In this article says to solve this kind of problem, the python telegram library provides a way to explicitly run a callback function (or any other function) in a separate thread.
Can some explain me how to do it with java ???

Here my parts of code:

BOT

```
@Component   
public class SenderBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

private static final String BOT_TOKEN = "token";
private static final String BOT_NAME = "bot_name";

static {
    ApiContextInitializer.init();
}

@Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

    if (update.hasMessage()) {
    ...
    some code
    ...
    }
}
}
```

SpringBootApp

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SenderBotApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SenderBot.class, args);
    }
}
```

If someone knows another way without multithreading - tell me how.
 
I would be very grateful for any help and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
@Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (update.hasMessage()) {
                // code goes here.
                }
              }
       }).start
}
```

This code works fine with many users at the same time.
But i don't know correct this solution or not...